# How to combine multiple Facebook API requests into one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to the Facebook API(s), and am trying to fetch all ad accounts associated with a user, and then subsequently fetch all pixels associated with each of those ad accounts:

```
const adAccounts = await facebookRequest({
  url: '/me/adaccounts',
  fields: ['name', 'owner'],
})
await Promise.all(
  adAccounts.map(async (adAccount) => {
    adAccount.pixels = await facebookRequest({
      url: `/${adAccount.id}/adspixels`,
      fields: ['name'],
    })
    return adAccount
  })
)
```

However, I had thought due to the GraphQL-y nature of Facebook's APIs that it'd somehow be possible to also query for the ad account pixels as an "edge" (is that correct terminology) on the initial request, to prevent multiple subsequent network roundtrips.

Is it possible to combine these requests somehow?

Comment: Not sure if it’s possible to work with [Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion) at this point, if not, then [Batch Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests/) would still be an option.

Comment: Field names and edges can be used somewhat interchangably in the `fields` parameter, so if you just add `'adspixels'` as an additional field here, aren’t you almost there already? Requesting specific sub-fields of the pixel would then again require Field Expansion syntax, something like `'adspixels{name,code}'` (assuming the SDK you are using there assembles that in the same syntax the API expects; when in doubt, test in Graph API explorer first.)